# Kmeans - putting k as the number of rows in the partition window / 10

Tags: postgis, clustering

I want that instead of using the same value of k for all my partitions as shown below, I should select k as the number of rows in the partition window / 10, is this even possible?

My current code is as follows (I am using same value of k for all partitions):

```
data as (
select a.name as uc_name,at2."name" as area_type, a.name,bf.* from building_footprints bf
left join area a on bf."areaID" = a."ID"
left join area_type at2 on at2."ID" = a."areaTypeID"


where 

at2."name"='Uc'
and a.name='M' or  a."name"='D' or  a."name"='R'
)

,
kmeans as (
select uc_name,"area_type", "name",
"ID",
"geoJson" ,
ST_ClusterKMeans(st_transform(data."geoJson",24313), (select (count(*)/10)::integer from data),50 ) OVER (partition by uc_name order by data."ID") AS cluster_id
FROM data
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've answered the question! here is how to proceed:

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT
        a.name AS uc_name,
        at2."name" AS area_type,
        a.name,
        bf.*
    FROM building_footprints bf
    LEFT JOIN area a ON bf."areaID" = a."ID"
    LEFT JOIN area_type at2 ON at2."ID" = a."areaTypeID"
    WHERE at2."name" = 'Uc' AND (a.name = 'M' OR a.name = 'D' OR a.name = 'R')
),
partition_counts AS (
    SELECT uc_name, COUNT(*) AS partition_size
    FROM data
    GROUP BY uc_name
)
,
kmeans AS (
    SELECT
        d.uc_name,
        d."area_type",
        d."name",
        d."ID",
        d."geoJson",
        ST_ClusterKMeans(
            ST_Transform(d."geoJson", 24313),
            (pc.partition_size / 10)::integer, -- Use dynamic k value
            50
        ) OVER (PARTITION BY d.uc_name ORDER BY d."ID") AS cluster_id
    FROM data d
    JOIN partition_counts pc ON d.uc_name = pc.uc_name
)
```

So basically, there is a new CTE added to the code for the counts per uc_name, then this CTE is joined to the data CTE.